# Filling a list within a loop using list.add and loop variable - how to clone variable?

Tags: dart

i try to read out a certain XML API. It is my first project in dart and not very optimized, however it works until the loop ... well loops.

Here the code:

```
getKategorie(XmlElement element) {
    Kategorie tmpKategorie = Kategorie();
    dynamic iterableElements;
    Board tmpBoard = Board();
    tmpKategorie.id = element.getAttribute("id");
    tmpKategorie.name = element.getElement("name")?.innerText;
    tmpKategorie.description = element.getElement("description")?.innerText;

    iterableElements = element.getElement("boards")?.childElements;
    for (XmlElement tmpElement in iterableElements) {
      if (tmpElement.localName == "board") {
        tmpBoard.id = tmpElement?.getAttribute("id");
        tmpBoard.name = tmpElement?.getElement("name")?.innerText;
        tmpBoard.description = tmpElement?.getElement("description")?.innerText;
        tmpKategorie.boards.add(tmpBoard);
      }
    }
    return tmpKategorie;
  }
```

the custom classes i use:

```
class Kategorie {
  List<Board> boards = [];
  dynamic id;
  dynamic name = "NN";
  dynamic description = "NN";
}

class Board {
  dynamic id;
  dynamic name;
  dynamic description;
}
```

Everything works fine until i reach the second Element with localName board. While the *tmpBoard* variable will be filled with the data from the second/third/whatever Element content, the before added list element in *tmpKategore.boards* is also changed.
It looks like the add call for the *tmpKategorie.boards* list is only putting in the reference to the loop variable *tmpBoard* which ends in my problem: At the end all added list entries are identical to the last one.

How can i copy the object instead of referencing it into the list?

**solution like suggested**

```
if (tmpElement.localName == "board") {
        tmpBoard.id = tmpElement?.getAttribute("id");
```

becomes

```
if (tmpElement.localName == "board") {
        tmpBoard = Board();
        tmpBoard.id = tmpElement?.getAttribute("id");
```

Comment: There is no built-way to clone arbitrary objects in Dart.  In this case, it seems like you don't even need to; why are you not constructing a new `tmpBoard` on each iteration of the loop instead?

Comment: thanks, how obvious :(
It shows again my missing/outdated understanding of darts philosophy.